# Matching a URL with RegExpObject.test() not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match the `document.URL` to `*google.co*/search/*` pattern as such

```
if (
        !(/google.*\/search/.test(document.URL))
    ){
    alert("hi");
```

but I can't figure out what's wrong, it's not working. **edit**: If the pattern is correct, then why isn't RegExpObject.test() function working as expected?

Because as shown below, the site ***is*** (or should be) matched by the pattern, and with the `!`not operator, I shouldn't be seeing the alert, yet I am.

[image]

---

**edit**: expressions were all correct (even mine own), I was just having cache-problems.

Comment: Try `/www\.google\.co.*\/search.*/`

Comment: **if (!(/\*www.google.co*\/search*/.test(document.URL)))
    {
    alert("hi");
    }**

it works for me what is your url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the regular expression:

```
/(.*\.)?google\.co.+\/search.*\/.*/
```

It will match following patterns:

```
google.com/search/
google.co.uk/search/

www.google.com/search/
www.google.co.uk/search/

google.com/search/query?...
google.com/search-any-pattern/query-any-pattern
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex looks suspicious.

See following code:

```
if ( !(/(www\.)?google\.co[^\/]+\/search/
       .test('https://www.google.com/search?q=find%20my%20iphone#q=find+empty+folders')) ) {
    alert("nope");
} else {
    alert("yup");
}
```

Will alert `"yup"`

So correct regex would be:

```
/(www\.)?google\.co[^\/]+\/search/
```

You don't need to match literal `*`